# Adding actions to the android keys(home,back,settings)

Tags: android

I made a launcher and with it comes two sliding drawers. One includes the apps, the other includes a webview. I want to add either software or hardware key actions to the app. Also, i want to add a toolstrip for the web view.

Comment: Please be more specific like what is the problem you faced while trying these things?

Comment: @prudhvi  its not a problem rather than i can add buttons to the webview but they wont view. Im adding gridview now